# TLS handshake fails between organizations

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am running a custom Hyperledger Fabric network with TLS enabled in all communications. Everyting looks great inside of an organizations and CLI can connect to its org peers with TLS and CLIENTAUTH enabled. This is the status of the network:

```
org1
  - peer0
    anchor: true
    tls_enabled: true
    tls_clientauth_enabled: true
  - peer1
    tls_enabled: true
    tls_clientauth_enabled: true
  - orderer0
    tls_enabled: true
    tls_clientauth_enabled: false
org2
  - peer0
    anchor: true
    tls_enabled: true
    tls_clientauth_enabled: true
  - peer1
    tls_enabled: true
    tls_clientauth_enabled: true
  - orderer0
    tls_enabled: true
    tls_clientauth_enabled: false
org3
  - orderer0
    tls_enabled: true
    tls_clientauth_enabled: false
```

However, once I start a channel than involves multiple organizations, I get Gossip and TLS hanshake related errors. This is an example (log from peer0.org1):

```
2019-10-07 10:01:45.615 UTC [gossip.service] func1 -> INFO 046 Elected as a leader, starting delivery service for channel global
2019-10-07 10:01:48.620 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 047 Failed connecting to {orderer0.org2:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]} , error: context deadline exceeded
2019-10-07 10:01:51.622 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 048 Failed connecting to {orderer0.org1:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]} , error: context deadline exceeded
2019-10-07 10:01:54.638 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 049 Failed connecting to {orderer0.org3:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]} , error: context deadline exceeded
2019-10-07 10:01:54.638 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 04a Could not connect to any of the endpoints: [{orderer0.org2:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]} {orderer0.org1:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]} {orderer0.org3:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]}]
2019-10-07 10:01:54.638 UTC [deliveryClient] connect -> ERRO 04b Failed obtaining connection: could not connect to any of the endpoints: [{orderer0.org2:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]} {orderer0.org1:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]} {orderer0.org3:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]}]
2019-10-07 10:01:54.638 UTC [deliveryClient] try -> WARN 04c Got error: could not connect to any of the endpoints: [{orderer0.org2:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]} {orderer0.org1:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]} {orderer0.org3:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]}] , at 1 attempt. Retrying in 1s
2019-10-07 10:01:58.640 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 04d Failed connecting to {orderer0.org2:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]} , error: context deadline exceeded
2019-10-07 10:01:59.833 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 04e TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.17.0.24:54590
2019-10-07 10:02:00.828 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 04f TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.17.0.24:54604
2019-10-07 10:02:01.642 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 050 Failed connecting to {orderer0.org1:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]} , error: context deadline exceeded
2019-10-07 10:02:02.609 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 051 TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.17.0.24:54624
2019-10-07 10:02:04.647 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 052 Failed connecting to {orderer0.org3:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]} , error: context deadline exceeded
2019-10-07 10:02:04.647 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 053 Could not connect to any of the endpoints: [{orderer0.org2:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]} {orderer0.org1:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]} {orderer0.org3:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]}]
2019-10-07 10:02:04.647 UTC [deliveryClient] connect -> ERRO 054 Failed obtaining connection: could not connect to any of the endpoints: [{orderer0.org2:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]} {orderer0.org1:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]} {orderer0.org3:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]}]
2019-10-07 10:02:04.647 UTC [deliveryClient] try -> WARN 055 Got error: could not connect to any of the endpoints: [{orderer0.org2:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]} {orderer0.org1:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]} {orderer0.org3:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]}] , at 2 attempt. Retrying in 2s
2019-10-07 10:02:04.755 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 056 TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.17.0.19:48822
2019-10-07 10:02:05.755 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 057 TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.17.0.19:48836
2019-10-07 10:02:07.118 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 058 TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.17.0.19:48854
2019-10-07 10:02:09.651 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 059 Failed connecting to {orderer0.org2:7050 [org1MSP org2MSP org3MSP]} , error: context deadline exceeded
2019-10-07 10:02:10.595 UTC [gossip.gossip] func1 -> WARN 05a Deep probe of peer0.org2:7051 failed: context deadline exceeded
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip.(*gossipServiceImpl).learnAnchorPeers.func1
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/gossip_impl.go:251
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/discovery.(*gossipDiscoveryImpl).Connect.func1
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/discovery/discovery_impl.go:153
runtime.goexit
        /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333
2019-10-07 10:02:10.595 UTC [gossip.discovery] func1 -> WARN 05b Could not connect to Endpoint: peer0.org2:7051, InternalEndpoint: peer0.org2:7051, PKI-ID: <nil>, Metadata:  : context deadline exceeded
```

How can I solve it? I tried to share CA Pems between orgs and set `CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS_FILES` to `"/public/org1/ca-chain.pem /public/org2/ca-chain.pem /public/org3/ca-chain.pem"`, but it does not work. Do I have to add the client cert for each peer/orderer to every one of my nodes? Where? Is this problem not related to TLS? I am really lost.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you specified `CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE`, `CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE` and `CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE` (this one is for the CA) for each peer?

And if you run your CA Server with TLS you have to specify the cert and keyfiles for TLS there as well.